# JQuery Animate ScrollTop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make the page scroll down to '.block3' on clicking the green block. What am I missing here? I can't seem to get it working and I checked similar threads with no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.down').click(function() {
    alert("y no work?");
    $('html', 'body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.block3').offset().top
    }, 800, "easeOutQuart");
  });
});
```

```css
.down {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.block1,.block2,.block3 {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="down"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
<div class="block3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `selector`. You can scroll only one element at a time. And for the easing you need extra libraries.

*I noticed your scroll is not reaching the end. I presume that's the indent*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.down').click(function() {
  $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('.block3').offset().top}, 800, 'linear');
 });
 
 });
```

```css
.down {background:green; width:50px; height:50px; }
.block1, .block2, .block3 { background:red; width:200px; height:600px; margin: 1em 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="down"></div>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2"></div>

<div class="block3"></div>
```

Comment: This is not actually correct, the problem is the way the selector is formatted, not that it's selecting multiple elements. It should be $('html, body'), NOT $('html', 'body') (notice the quotes)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

**You must Seperate each selector with a comma.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.down').click(function() {
        
        alert("y no work?");
        
        $('html,body').animate({
            
            scrollTop: $('.block3').offset().top}, 800, "linear");
    })
    
})
```

```css
 .down {background:green; width:50px; height:50px; }
.block1, .block2, .block3 { background:red; width:200px; height:600px; margin: 1em 0;}
```

```html
<div class="down"></div>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2"></div>

<div class="block3"></div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you don't have JQuery UI, that could be the reason why `easeOutQuart` is not working, linear is fine if you don't want to use `easeOutQuart`.

To include `easeOutQuart` or other special ui, include [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just include jquery UI

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<div class="down"></div>

<div class="block1"></div>

<div class="block2"></div>

<div class="block3"></div>
<style>
.down {background:green; width:50px; height:50px; }
.block1, .block2, .block3 { background:red; width:200px; height:600px; margin: 1em 0;}
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.down').click(function() {
        alert("y no work?");
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('.block3').position().top}, 800, "easeOutQuart");
 });
 
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

library then try again everything your scripts should perfectly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('.block3').position().top}, 800, "easeOutQuart");
```

Use top + object height:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('.block3').position().top + $('.block3').height()}, 800, "easeOutQuart");
```